# is 'git add' necessary when trustExitCode = true?

Tags: git

I know that I should use git add after the conflict is resolved. I've recently noticed the trustExitCode option for mergetool. When the selected mergetool returns good exit code do I still need to use git add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I don't need to `git add` after I resolved the conflict using a `mergetool` with a trusted exit code.

If the merged file was not touched by the `mergetool`, Git will ask you if the merge was successful nonetheless. In this case, if you tell it that the merge was successful, Git will automatically add the merged file.